# How is class diagram supposed to be?

Tags: php, architecture, uml, class-diagram

I have participated in a coding competition in which I am supposed to create a 'Virtual Library'. In our first submission we are supposed to submit the high level specifications of our web application. Along with that we are supposed to submit the architecture diagram and class diagram. Can someone please explain what class diagram and architecture diagrams mean? I am planning to develop the application using PHP. I tried to google up what those two mean. I didnot get a clear definition of architecture. And the explanation of class diagram involved the concepts like class, method, attributes etc. which do not exactly apply to PHP. Please help. How should I design those two diagrams? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class diagram shows (as its name says) the classes which will be involved in your program. Talking about a virtual library you will have some classes called Book, User and so on. This diagram shows how those classes are connected, the multiplicity (1-1, 1-m,m-m..) and the fields that each class contains.

This diagram will help you to understand better how the objects will be connected, and make sure before start programming that there are no problems with your idea (and if you are working in a group, assure that everyone has the same idea regarding to the developing plan).
If you develop your application in PHP, you could do it in an object oriented way, so you could easly design the diagram.

By asking you to do this diagrams, I think they assume you will do it object oriented.
You may also like the take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php